# htacces failing to remove index.php completely leaves /? in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My site went completely `https` and I am having trouble to remove the `/index.php?/` from the `urls`.

When I try to open the website like so: `example.com/links` the page redirects to `https://example.com/?/links` I cannot seem to remove the `/?` part. I have tried many different approaches, but I am not a htaccess/regex hero. This is the closest I have come to getting it right. Some help would be appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule cache/ - [F]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule cache/ - [F]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to test this it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the issue. Thank you, i understand what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Fist redirect to https (R=302 =temp, R=301 =permanent) and stop checking other rules (L), then remove index.php. Otherwise it redirects to that url how it sees it at that time.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule cache/ - [F]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Thank you for adding an explanation! Clears things up for me.